# React communicate between component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have context, where the state of the variable is getting updated every second. And I want  invoke functions in other component whenever the variable in the state reaches certain value [second equals 0]

**State in the context**

```
const initialState = {
  second: new Date().getSeconds()
};
```

I'm able to get the value is other components as below

```
  const [secState, dispatch] = useContext(SecContext);
 `secState.second`
```

1. Can someone please guide how to invoke a function when `secState.second` is zero
2. I thought of triggering event in the useContext whenever the value reaches zero and listening on other component. not sure how to do it in react any hints or reference please

Answer (score 1):

Inside your components you can have an effect that runs when the context's second value updates, and executes something if it's 0. So in the component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (second === 0) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}, [second]);
```

Comment: Agreed, is there way where we can call a function only when the value reaches zero. Something like dispatching a event, rather than checking for this condition in all the components, i can centralize it in  context class

Comment: here the useEffect will be invoked every second trying to avoid that

Comment: @upog It doesn't really matter though, the component is connected to the context so it'll re-render every time the second changes anyway. It's hardly anything extra to invoke the use effect as well, if performance is what you're worried about

Comment: And hooks with dependencies are the main way to simulate a "listener" type functionality in React. You could use vanilla event listeners, but that's usually only for certain edge cases, like hooking into document loading or scrolling. Not usually just for a regular old number value